# How to get theme specific cms page links in front end?

Tags: magento-1.7, cms

I have two themes (desktop and iphone) for same store view.
I have created cms pages for both the themes differently due to different look.
so **there are 2 about-us pages, 2 contact-us pages**..and so on..

Now there is a link called "sitemap" in which all the links of cms pages and categories is showing.
The problem is..
both the links of cms pages are displaying.

The function resoponsible for getting cms pages is as follows..

```
public function getCMSPages(){

    $storeId = $this->helper('core')->getStoreId();
    $cms = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1)
                    ->addStoreFilter($storeId);
    $url = Mage::getBaseUrl();
    $html = "";
    foreach($cms as $cmspage):
        $page = $cmspage->getData();    
        if($page['identifier'] == "no-route" || $page['identifier'] == "enable-cookies" || $page['identifier'] == "empty"){
             /* do nothing */
         } else {
            if($page['identifier'] == "home"){
                $html .= "<li><a href=\"$url\" title=\"".$page['title']."\">".$page['title']."</a></li>\n";
            } else {
                $html .= "<li><a href=\"$url".$page['identifier']."\" title=\"".$page['title']."\">".$page['title']."</a></li>\n";
            }
        }
    endforeach;

    return $html;   
}
```

Now What I want is..
How can I get **theme specific cms page links** in the frontend ?

Comment: you can get the cms page according to the url key of that particular page

Comment: @Manashvibirla, I have to show all the links in the front end. Because I have created 2 pages for same cms (1 for desktop, 1 for iphone). So it is showing both the links.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a same name CMS page.

Then got to that CMS page .

```
GOTO Page-> Design -> Custom Design -> Select Your Theme .
```

Comment: hi @HiteshVaghasiya, same name refers to same "URL Key" or "page title" ?

Comment: @Kishore Yes , "URL Key" or "page title" are same and content as you want but just you have to set only theme .

Comment: "A page URL key for specified store already exists." error coming while creating with same url key.

Comment: I Thinks this link help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348589/magento-different-home-page-for-each-theme-but-using-same-store-view-and-with